# Node-sass doesn't have binding with node version which uses in TestCafe Docker Image

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Initially, i faced the issue, that concurrency doesn't work in Jenkins. I find [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3272) issue in official repository and followed advise to update Testcafe Docker Image to latest version (i took it from testcafe/testcafe repository). However, now i faced another issue. We have `node-sass` package using for web app which i test, and `node-sass` doesn't work with Node 10.x and displays this error message

```
Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /tests/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux_musl-x64-64/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux/musl 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux/musl 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

Is there is some workaround for it, or maybe Testcafe can use Node 8.x and then you can provide Docker Image with this node version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment we do not have plans to create multiple testcafe docker images for different node versions. However, I created a separate [feature request](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3480).
Please track that ticket and vote for it. We can add it to our plans in the future.